# how to filter only port 80 and 443 at mod_status of apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

Is there a way to show only requests of port 80 and 443 when looking /server-status of mod_status ?

My /etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
        # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
        # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
        # Uncomment and change the "192.0.2.0/24" to allow access from other hosts.

        <Location /server-status>
                SetHandler server-status
                #Require local
                #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
 Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
        </Location>

        # Keep track of extended status information for each request
        ExtendedStatus On

        # Determine if mod_status displays the first 63 characters of a request or
        # the last 63, assuming the request itself is greater than 63 chars.
        # Default: Off
        #SeeRequestTail On


        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
                # Show Proxy LoadBalancer status in mod_status
                ProxyStatus On
        </IfModule>


</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not.

[Server-status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html) is to see - like the name say - information about Apache server and about specific pages or port.

Maybe "apachetop" can help you.

Comment: apachetop is a module?

Comment: It's a software http://linux.die.net/man/1/apachetophttp://linux.die.net/man/1/apachetop